# (Sweetalert2 Toast) How to disable ENTER/SPACE, ESC & click outside the box?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Tried the following and they doesn't seem compatible.

1. allowOutsideClick
2. allowEscapeKey
3. allowEnterKey

Is there a workaround to be able to prevent Enter, ESC & click outside the Toast popup box? So the users must have to wait for the popup to close to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to catch event and disable it with event.preventDefault ()

```js
document.write("press a key")
document.addEventListener("keypress",(e)=>{
        if(e.keyCode==27 || e.keyCode==13){
          e.preventDefault()
          alert(" you can't press esc or enter")
        }
        else document.write("key press:"+e.keyCode)
        })
document.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
if(e.path[0].className!=="myAlert"){
  e.preventDefault()
  alert("you can't press out")
  }
})
```

```css
.myAlert{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: red;
     color: white;
     text-alin
}
```

```html
<div class="myAlert">
  Click me
</div>
```

> 

[visit the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)